# Checking for string equality when the string contains punctuation

Tags: php, string, equality

Can PHP check for equality when punctation marks are within a string? I tried comparing `hello'` with `hello'` and they are not equal when compared with `==`.

Comment: You should use `===` unless you expect the compared values to be typecast. While is is not the reason for your problem, it would be a bit better practice.

Answer (score 0):

It compares the strings correctly:

```
"hello'" == "hello'" // true
```

[Codepad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/llwSq1)

You must be doing something else wrong. Perhaps you are using `'` in a single quoted string without escaping it like `\'` and are getting weird results.